# Why is the code not allowing the list to print?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Ive just started making a (very basic, im new to python) student database which you can insert students and details or view students and their details. Here's the code so far -

```
name = []
age = []
year = []
chosen_subjects =[]
classroom=[]
seat_number=[]
comments=[]
student = [name, age, year, chosen_subjects, classroom, seat_number, comments]


print ("Welcome to Student Database")
print()

while True:
    eorv = input("Press E to enter a new student or V to view existing students ")
    print()
    if eorv == "E" or "e":
        ename = input("Enter student's name")
        name.append(ename)

        eage = input("Enter student's age")`
        age.append(eage)

        eyear = input("Enter student's year")
        year.append(eyear)

        echosen_subjects = input("Enter student's chosen subjects")
        chosen_subjects.append(echosen_subjects)

        eclassroom = input("Enter student's classroom")
        classroom.append(eclassroom)

        eseat_number = input("Enter student's seat number")
        seat_number.append(eseat_number)

        ecomment = input("Enter any comment about this student")
        comments.append(ecomment)
```

This seems to be where the problem is

```
    elif eorv == "V" or "v":
        print (student)
```

When "V" is pressed, it just asks all the questions from "E". Im not sure why this is, can someone help?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but can't find it ATM. The problem is the order of evaulation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, that's the one :)

Comment: @WayneWerner FYI: http://sopython.com/canon/

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh that's nice. Thanks!

Comment: Ah thanks that helped me out @jonrsharpe

Comment: You should be able to choose to accept the duplicate, in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks to be with your if and elif statements. This works for me.

```
if eorv == "E" or eorv == "e":
```

Same goes for your elif

```
if eorv == "V" or eorv == "v:
```